# AngularJS oauth endpoint with hash in url (SpotifyAPI)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, spotify

I want to receive the oauth callback from Spotify and have problems with the `#` in my URL.

routes.js

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      ...
      when('/callback', {
        templateUrl: 'views/callback.html',
        controller: 'CallbackCtrl'
      })
      ...
  }]);
```

So to access that route the URL is e. g. `http://test.com/#/callback`

For the spotify endpoint the `redirect_uri` has to be url-encoded:

`https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize/?client_id=...&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2F%23%2Fcallback&scope=user-read-private%20user-read-email&state=profile%2Factivity`

The redirect from spotify:

`http://test.com/%23/callback?code=..&state=profile%2Factivity`

Which results in a 404

I know there are some workarounds like using the `/` route or enabling html5mode to get rid of the `#` but I hope there is a true solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well your situation is not that awkward at all.

Since you can't control the way that spotify's redirect after OAuth works, it leaves you with two options:

1) Create a URL Path for example `http://test.com/redirect_uri/?code=....` which will automatically redirect the user to the webapp in the state of logged in.

**This method is not a good practice, unless you really know exactly what you are doing. The major problem here is security. Unless you add really good Mechanism to the redirection page.**

2) Easier, and actually better in all aspects:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` 
A small introduction on this:

Why does this remove the `#`? Because when HTML5 mode is on, it will use history to refer to native paths in your app.

But hold on this is not the only thing you have to do:
You have to redirect all request to go through the main page normally `index.html`.

I use to do this with .htaccess, But since of AngularJS 1.3 I know there is another method with adding `meta` tag of `<base href=/base/path/of/app/directory">`. Usually `<base href="/">`

But I still prefer .htacces rewriterule or w/e webserver you are using accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are going to implement the Authorization Code flow client-side, exposing the secret key you were provided when you register your app. This is wrong, since someone might generate tokens on behalf of your application using the client id and secret key.

A better approach is to either use Implicit Grant (in example how it is done on https://github.com/possan/webapi-player-example) or implement the token exchange server-side and pass the token to your AngularJS webapp.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/angular/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag) article on Scotch.io for "pretty URL's" that should fix this issue.

You will have to set html5Mode to true:

```
// Remember to inject $locationProvider
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Then, include a base in the  of your html file:

```
<base href="/">
```

This will let you navigate the webpage using relative links.

The article I mentioned also goes into fallbacks for older browsers.